# apply shadow to transparent view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, view, shadow, transparent

I want to make a view inside the dash (`3 m/s`)
[image]

So I thought it would be fine if I apply a shadow to the outside of the transparent Circle.
Like this.
[image]

So I wrote the code below, but when I fill .clear color, I couldn't get a shadow.

```swift
Circle()
    .fill(.clear)
    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3),
            radius: 10)
    .padding()
```

[image]

Any idea to apply shadow to transparent view?

Comment: It's not possible to set shadow on clear view. It doesn't make sense to add shadow on noting. your view seems blurred so you can give .blur a try.

Comment: .blur to stroke would be nice like this. `Circle().stroke(.black.opacity(0.3)).blur(radius: 4)`

Comment: @Vahid It does make sense and there are use cases. I would like to use it in a list in the sidebar of a navigationsplitview to create an effect  similar to the default list style but with more spacing between rows. I can do this using a white rounded rectangle and shadow around but when selected the view should turn accentcolor, because the part of the list row around does this as well. If just the rectangle would be clear I wouldn't have to worry about selection with .onTapGesture bc of  support for <iOS 16. There it should look like a shadow not like stroke (with blur)